# How to declare global variables?

Tags: c#

I have a doubt regarding Memory Management in Variables declaration.

In my class i have around 20 methods, i am using around 50 variables through out my class.

I declared all variables globally at the starting of a class.

Is it the right way of doing? or else which one is better... Using structure or any thing else???

Below am showing a basic example, i need to use optimize my memory.

```
  class Program
    {
        static  int a, b, c, d;           //----> Here am declaring , i need any other way
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            a = 10;
            b = 20;
            c = 30;
            d = 40;

            int result = add(a, b, c, d);
            Console.WriteLine(result);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        public static int add(int w, int x, int y, int z)
        {
            return w + x + y + z;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Using global variables is considered bad practice in general. What makes you think you need global scope?

Comment: What are these 50 variables for  ? Can u tell more clearly ?

Comment: Don't prematurely optimize.  "i need to use optimize my memory"  No, chances are you don't.  Is your program/machine crashing because it uses too much memory?  You should be scoping your variables based on what makes the program easiest to read, understand, manage, etc., not based on how much memory it consumes until you *know* that it's using more than is acceptable.  An extra int or two (or 50) in memory is virtually never going to be an issue.  That said, you should avoid global variables for design reasons where possible.

Comment: Instead of defining variable every time in a Method I declared it in Globally...Isn't it good practice??? If so can you suggest which one is better?

Comment: Are your global variables actually constants, or do you have to modify them? It is not bad practice to declare constants global (use const instead of static). Using static variables just to avoid local declarations is terrible practice however

Comment: @YUG No, that's not a good practice.  If you only need a variable inside of a method, keep it inside of that method.

Comment: In the below case i have used variables a and b in method 1 and method2 so u people are suggesting that  to declare them at locally

public static int Method1(int a1)
        {
            var a = 15;
            var b = 10;
            int res = a * b;
            return res * a1;

        }
        public static int Method2(int a1)
        {
            var a = 100;
            var b = 10;
            int res = a * b;
            return res * a1;
        }

Answer (score 5):

Your class-level variables are only used within a single method, so declare them only within the scope of that method:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var a = 10;
    var b = 20;
    var c = 30;
    var d = 40;

    int result = add(a, b, c, d);
    Console.WriteLine(result);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

As a rule of thumb, keep your variables as close to their use as possible.  Any time the scope has to increase, step back and think about the structure.  Don't just blindly move the variables up in scope.

Is there a reason you're trying to optimize the resource consumption of your code?  Chances are, especially in a case this simple, the compiler is doing a fine job of this already.  Unless you're seeing actual problems, don't prematurely optimize.  More often than not this results in unmanageable code.

Also, and this is a side note because I understand that this is a contrived example... Meaningful variable *names* are very important.  Meaningful names also help you understand and identify the desired scope of your variables.  If a variable is called `a` then that doesn't give you any context about what it means.  But if the name tells you what it means then you can more readily visualize what context in the code is actually responsible for that value, resulting in better scope definition.

Comment: In the below case i have used variables a and b in method 1 and method2 so u people are suggesting that to declare them at locally....... public static int Method1(int a1) { var a = 15; var b = 10; int res = a * b; return res * a1; } public static int Method2(int a1) { var a = 100; var b = 10; int res = a * b; return res * a1; }

Comment: @YUG: Again, the example is _too_ contrived.  There's _no_ context about what these variables mean, what these methods do, what the object is, etc.  Without any meaningful context, I'd err on the side of local scope instead of global scope.  In your comment above, I see no compelling reason to move `a`, `b`, or `res` to a more global scope.  Just because the method implementations do very similar things doesn't mean their internal implementations should be exposed externally.  Prefer single-responsibility over micro-optimizations.