# declaring a variable global in c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I am developing a windows phone 7 app and need to declare variables as global so that the information they carry can be used anywhere in the application.

I tried this by declaring variables as public static. I tried almost all the possibilities i could think of but none worked. can we make variables global? If yes, how?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10285021/how-to-declare-global-variables?rq=1    Possible duplicate

Comment: you tried by declaring variables as public static. Then what happened?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a global variable, `public static` is what you need. However, you should prefer using properties rather than public variables:

```
 public class GlobalData {
     private static string someString = "Hello, world!";
     public static string SomeString {
         get {return someString;}
         set {someString = value;}
     }
 }
```

You refer to this global variable using a fully qualified name, like this:

```
GlobalData.SomeString = "Quick brown fox";
Console.WriteLine("Global variable value is '{0}'", GlobalData.SomeString);
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try putting your global variables inside of a public class and referencing them by the class name and than the variable name?

```
public static class GlobalVariables {
    public static int MrGlobalInt = 5;
}
...
GlobalVariables.MrGlobalInt = 10;
```